# Google rankings tanked a month ago, can't understand why

Tags: seo, ranking, technical-seo, seo-audit, ahrefs

Started my site in July 2022, but it never started to rank. Might be because I messed up trying to make it multi-language.

**301 redirect**

Because my site never started to rank, I did a 301 redirect to a new domain in April 2023. After that the site slowly started to rank until July 10th.

**Traffic tanking**

Google rankings completely tanked between July 9th and July 10th, so since July 10th I haven't really got any traffic from Google :(

[image]

Ahrefs Site Audit doesn't report any errors. Average engagement time on my site is ~2 minutes and I have ~5 page views per session.

My problem is that I can't see why my traffic has tanked. I have checked Ahrefs Site Audit and everything is ok there. Same with Google Analytics, reporting good user engagement.

**What now?**

My problem now is I don't know where to look for more information, so I can find out what's wrong on my site.

i.e. how do find the cause of traffic tanking when I have checked Ahrefs Site Audit and Google Analytics and not seen any issues there?

Comment: How can we, without more information

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Got it. I have tried to clarify my problem a bit.